# Page url showing page/2 but getting posts from first page

Tags: wordpress, pagination

I'm struggling a theme that I got, the theme uses `query_posts()` and pagination used to work. Now pagination is not working on this page, and it keeps on showing posts from the first page on the second. Meaning, the url shows `page/2` but I keep on seeing the first posts of the category, i.e. the first 4 on every page.

Here is the code used to get the posts:

```
global $current_category;

$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
global $query_string;

$args = "";
if ($current_category['post_type'] == "product") {          
    $args=array(
        'showposts' => 4,
        'paged' => $paged,
        'post_type' => 'product'
    );
} else {
    $args=array(
        'showposts' => 4,
        'category_name' => $current_category['name'],
        'paged' => $paged
    );
}
query_posts($args);
```

And here's the loop:

```
if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
    <outputs code here>
endwhile;
else :
    <output no results code here>
endif;

if ( is_home() ) wp_reset_query();
```

Now, can anybody please point me in the right direction?

//update:

I have already tried [this solution](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/paged-page-2-etc-not-working) as well, so far, I can only tell that the `paged` variable never gets updated in the query.

//update 2:

This page was done custom, and setting it as the home page via **Settings -> Reading** inhibits the above behaviour. When leaving it as a normal page, and setting home as recent posts, the pagination works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this after some very long research. My code now looks as follows:

```
global $current_category, $paged;

if ( get_query_var('paged') ) {
    $paged = get_query_var('paged');
} elseif ( get_query_var('page') ) {
    $paged = get_query_var('page');
} else {
    $paged = 1;
}
```

This just replaces the first 3 lines of the original code in the answer. The rest looks exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

if you have any custom queries in the template, make sure to integrate the `'paged'` parameter.

[Pagination Parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters)

Go through these codex pages:

[Preserving Existing Query Parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts#Preserving_Existing_Query_Parameters)

Related: [Pagination](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts#Pagination)

Comment: As you can see, I did incorporate `paged` into my query. It didn't work.